# Ionic and Angular app, bottom tabs are blocking the content and scroll

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, tabs

I have an Ionic and Angular app, and when I add tabs to the bottom of my page (outside the ion-content), the scroll stops working inside the ion-content and the fab button which is inside the ion-content, is covering the tabs.

How can I make this work, I've tried moving it inside the ion-content, which just results in there being a bar of tabs in the middle of my icons that moves with the scroll.

Here is my code:

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="top" selected-tab="ownedProjects">
      <ion-tab-button tab="ownedProjects">
        <ion-label>Owned</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="subscribers">
        <ion-label>Subscribers</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>,

  <div id="ownedProjectsCardContainer" class="ion-margin-top ion-padding-top" overflow-scroll="true">
    <ion-card *ngFor="let project of user.projects" class="ion-margin-top">
      <img width="100%" [src]="project.projectImage" />
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle>{{ project.lastUpdated }} - <span class="{{ (project.status).toLowerCase() }}">{{ project.status }}</span></ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title>{{ project.name }}</ion-card-title>
        <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end">
          <ion-fab-button>
            <ion-icon name="pencil-outline"></ion-icon>
          </ion-fab-button>
        </ion-fab>
      </ion-card-header>
    </ion-card>

    <ng-container *ngIf="user.projects.length == 0" [ngTemplateOutlet]="noProjects"></ng-container>
  </div>

  <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>

</ion-content>

<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="home">
      <ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="search">
      <ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="notifications">
      <ion-icon name="notifications-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge>6</ion-badge>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="profile">
      <ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to use tabs for navigation in your app is creating app with template "tabs"

```
ionic start appName tabs
```

you can read more about creating [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/starting) and about tabs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs).

Comment: I can't do that at this point as there are several other people also working on the same project files. I've read about tabs - however, that doesn't change what happens when I try to use them.